Possible Improvements to sum(int n) function or calling code in C++
I have a function that calculates sum of the numbers up to a number N and returns it back to calling code as follows:
long sumUpToNumber(int n){
    long sum;
    return sum = n * (n + 1) / 2;
}

int main()
{
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 1; sum<INT_MAX; i++){
        sum = sumUpToNumber(i);
        if (sum >= INT_MAX)
            cout << "Maximum number N before overflow is: " << i - 1 << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}

This code appears to be doing the right thing but it is taking forever. If  that something i can do to improve it?
I have tried with smaller numbers where sum<1000 and code returns quickly and accurately but running it up to a sum<INT_MAX is taking a long time and I have stopped the it multiple times thinking there could be a logical error.

Wouldn't be easier to just solve it analytically n^2 + n - 2*INT_MAX == 0 ?

Could you not avoid brute-forcing your way so much? The result is likely to be very close to sqrt(2 * INT_MAX). Just think of a way to avoid the overflow of 2*INT_MAX. Since you are using signed int; it should not be too hard...

It is not just taking seemingly forever, it may be taking literally forever, compiling to an infinite loop as seen in .L4: jmp .L4.

sum is an int in  main, so both sum<INT_MAX and sum = sumUpToNumber(i);  will not behave how you may think. Also, n * (n + 1) / 2; is performed with int type, no matter what result is.

if (sum >= INT_MAX) is going to land you into problems anyway there can be no int larger than INT_MAX (there is no guarantee in C++ that long actually contains more bits than int). Also this is C++ so you can use std::uint32_t and std::uint64_t to be more precise and you should NOT be using "C"'s INT_MAX but std::numeric_limits<std::uint32_t>::max()

If sum overflows you will have undefined behavior.
What is likely to happen is that sum will become negative and your loop will continue to loop, possibly forever.
If you need to check for int overflow, use a type that is guaranteed to be larger than int, like long long.

Unfortunately, while long long is guaranteed to be at least as large as int, it's not actually guaranteed to be any larger (they could both be 64 bits, for example). Fortunately, it will usually be larger. Once you have the right type, Googling for binary search might lead to a faster way to find what you're looking for.

Like pptaszni said in his comment, this is easy to solve analytically:
n(n+1)/2 = x  => n^2 + n - 2x = 0

Apply the Polynomial Roots formula:
(-b +- sqrt(b^2 - 4*a*c)) / 2a   =>   (-1 + sqrt(1+8x)) / 2    (the - option leads to negative results)

Insert x = 2^31 (signed 32-bit max) and you get a root at 65535.5, while x = 2^32 (unsigned 32-bit max) finds a root at 92681.4. Naturally both has to be rounded down to get the highest number you can sum to before overflow.
On the other hand, if you really want to do it with code you need to make sure to keep your sums in variables that can actually hold them. Also, if you want to brute-force it in a loop from 0 up, there is really no reason to use Eulers formula each step - just sum the numbers as you walk on up:
#include <cstdint>
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>

int main()
{
    std::int64_t sum = 0;
    std::int64_t i = 0;
    while (sum < std::numeric_limits<std::int32_t>::max())
    {
        ++i;
        sum += i;
    }

    std::cout <<"Sum overflows after: "<< i - 1 << '\n';
}

This prints: Sum overflows after: 65535
For the second result change to: std::numeric_limits<std::uint32_t>::max(), then you get: Sum overflows after: 92681
